# Tweepy Python, retrieving latest 5 instances of a hashtag

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to retrieve all tweets that contain a certain hashtag and return the latest 5, ideally then update the list every minute.

I have been able to authorize an app with the documentation, although I cant see a method of searching for a hash-tag then retrieving the tweet.text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple example on how to retrieve a hashtag:

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'yourconsumerkey'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'yourconsumersecret'
ACCESS_KEY = 'youraccesskey'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'yoursecret'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

search_text = "#gamedev"
search_number = 2
search_result = api.search(search_text, rpp=search_number)
for i in search_result:
    print i.text
```